# MS SQL, JavaScript, HTML table connection

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server

Data from MS SQL is showing in JavaScript in Output (as i wanted) when i run the code. Now, I want to show my data (name, id) in HTML via localhost. Do you have any clues how to make it work?I don't know where to start, because i'm a beginner in javascript so i tried only the simpliest ways like `<script src="index.js"></script>` but it obviously didn't work.

If it helps, I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePi0HIz-6pE this to make my JS work.

You asked me for more code from `index.js` so here it is:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

var config={
    database: 'name',
    server: 'name',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options:{
        trustedConnection:true
    }

};

sql.connect(config,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    var request = new sql.Request();
    
    request.query('select * from animal.species', function(err,recordSet){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(recordSet)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: JavaScript running in the browser is running inside a sandbox. It can only make connections that the browser allows it to make, via HTTP and web sockets. So, making a connection from JavaScript running in the browser directly to a DBMS system is not possible - you instead need to have some server side HTTP server to serve as the bridge between the two - you could run one with Node, or Java, or .NET, or just about any other language/web framework.

Comment: @Enderlith could you please display the code from `index.js`? This [article](https://itnext.io/how-to-create-interactive-terminal-like-website-888bb0972288) written by the author of jQuery Terminal should help. The section *JavaScript Terminal with asynchronous commands* has an example using a `fetch()` call. The example uses `r.text()`. Assuming your MS SQL data is returned as JSON from the server, you would use `r.json()` instead of _r.text()_. Use of the `Response.json()` method is demonstrated on this [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mason so i need to make something like "app.js", which makes localhost run, and include there my index.js? Sorry if i sound dumb, i am really new to this

Comment: You need to pick a server side framework/language. If you want to stick with JavaScript as your language, you can use Node or any of several other JavaScript based app hosting models for your server. I'm not going to tell you what you should use, as part of the process of getting started is learning to research what your options are and make an informed decision about what to use.